# How to use Tkinter menus insert_cascade

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to insert a menu at a given index using the insert_cascade() method. From what I understand the parameters it takes are the same as add_cascade() method plus integer index number of where you want to insert at. But I can't get it to work I get the error below.

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2900, in insert_cascade
    self.insert(index, 'cascade', cnf or kw)
TypeError: insert() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I have tried hard coding the index and use the same parameters as I use with add_cascade() method, add_cascade() works fine.

Here is the call

```
parent.insert_cascade(self.index, **self.opts)
```

`self.index` is a `int`.
`self.options` is a `dict`.

```
class Menu(_MenuBase, tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, key, **data):
        _MenuBase.__init__(self, parent, key, **data)
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)

        if self.inherit:
            self.cfg = {**parent.cfg, **self.cfg}

        self.config(**self.cfg)

        if self.index is not None:
            parent.insert_cascade(self.index, **self.opts)
        else:
            parent.add_cascade(**self.opts)

        self.opts['image'] = self.image_name

        for key, item in data.items():
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                if item['type'] in ('Menu', 'MenuItem', 'MenuSeparator', 'MenuCheckbutton', 'MenuRadiobutton'):
                    self.nodes[key] = globals()[item['type']](self, key, **item)
```

Comment: show minimal working code with this problem so we could run it.

Comment: I have added my class to show how it's used, like I said above add_cascade() works.

Comment: don't use `**` to put dictionary - because it unpack values from dictionary and put as separated arguments.

Comment: It works for add_cascade(), I don't think that's the problem. http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#menu.Menu.add-method

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `self.opts` is what you think it is? Please provide a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: show FULL error message - it show problem with `insert()`, not `insert_cascade()`

Comment: Yes I have.

self.index = 0

self.opts =  {'label': 'File', 'underline': 0, 'menu': <menubar.menubar.Menu object .!menubar.!menu>, 'image': None, 'compound': 'left'}

Comment: Error is:

  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2900, in insert_cascade
    self.insert(index, 'cascade', cnf or kw)
TypeError: insert() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that additional information. Python code is impossible to understand when posted in the comments.

Comment: It's a bit hard to believe that the error complains about four unexpected parameters when you claim that `self.opts` contains five keys and values.

Comment: @furas: `insert_cascade` is just a wrapper around `insert`, which probably explains why there is an error with `insert` rather than `insert_cascade`.

Comment: I updated the full error message, I hope this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197845/discussion-between-daniel-huckson-and-bryan-oakley).

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou to all those who responded. I found the issue and know why my code was failing. The project I'm working on is somewhat complex and has code in multiple files which for obvious reasons I didn't want to post here. I going to explain what happen so others can benefit from my mistake.

This is the class definition  class Menu(_MenuBase, tk.Menu)

As you can see my class subclasses two other classes "_MenuBase, tk.Menu".
In _MenuBase I had a method,  def insert(self, uri=None, **data).
It was this method that was causing a naming conflict. I fixed that and all was good.